# Pointer passed by reference isn't updated?

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a feature that requires me to get a pointer to an item in a struct, and then save the initial value of it. I have tried to replicate the problem with a small block of code that does the exact same thing but that block works everytime. The method updates the pointer locally but not in the struct.

`float*& target` and `float& targetInitial` are the values i'm trying to change.

```
static void lfoTargetCombo(const char* name, const char** currentItem, float*& target, float& targetInitial)
{
    static const char* targetStrs[] = { "None", "Oscillator1 Volume", "Oscillator2 Volume", "LFO1 Rate", "LFO2 Rate",
        "LFO1 Amount", "LFO2 Amount", "Amplitude Envelope Attack", "Amplitude Envelope Decay", "Amplitude Envelope Sustain",
        "Amplitude Envelope Release" };

    if (ImGui::BeginCombo(name, *currentItem))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < IM_ARRAYSIZE(targetStrs); i++)
        {
            bool selected = (*currentItem == targetStrs[i]);
            if (ImGui::Selectable(targetStrs[i], selected))
            {
                *currentItem = targetStrs[i];
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    uintptr_t addr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&vars.osc1Volume) + (i - 1) * sizeof(float);
                    target = reinterpret_cast<float*>(addr);
                    targetInitial = *target;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ImGui::EndCombo();
    }
}

void foo()
{
    static const char* currentItem = "None";
    lfoTargetCombo("LFO1 Target", &currentItem, vars.lfo1Target, vars.lfo1Initial); 
    //Should result in vars.lfo1Target to be something that isn't nullptr
}
```

```
static struct GUIVars
{
    float osc1Volume = 0.5, osc2Volume = 0.5;
    float lfoRate1 = 1, lfoRate2 = 1;
    float lfoAmount1 = 0, lfoAmount2 = 0;
    float aeAttack = 0.5, aeDecay = 0.5, aeSustain = 0.5, aeRelease = 0.5;
    float osc1Shift = 0, osc2Shift = 0;
    int osc1Shape = 0, osc2Shape = 0;
    int lfo1Shape = 0, lfo2Shape = 0;

    float* lfo1Target, *lfo2Target;
    float lfo1Initial, lfo2Initial;
} vars;
```

I have been trying to fix this for way too long and I can not figure out why this is happening.

Comment: *"I have tried to replicate the problem with a small block of code that does the exact same thing but that block works everytime."* Make incremental changes to that block of code to make it more like the code you've shown us until you reproduce the problem. Then you'll know that the last change you've made is causing the problem.

Comment: I would suggest simplifying your test case. I don't see an obvious problem but I do see via your inner 'addr' assignment the function has access to 'vars', so my first question is why not get rid of the parameters and just use the structure directly?

Comment: What did you find out when you ran your code through the debugger?

Comment: `target = ...` is not generally broken, so it can be only `addr` or one of the conditions or loops bounds or the way you inspect `target` after calling the function, be that isnt what you think it is. A debugger can tell you where your expecations are off

Comment: When I inspect all of the values inside the function, they are all set correctly. Interestingly however, the address addr gets is not the same as the what the visual studio memory inspector tells me. It is very very close though.